# Django rest framework - how to use default_timezone?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Field in my serializer:

```
date_from = serializers.DateTimeField(default_timezone=settings.TIME_ZONE)
```

My settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

Data in admin site:
[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGSWz.png)

And date in the response:

```
    "date_from": "2016-12-23T21:00:00Z"
```

I understand  it returns the time in UTC, but how can I get time in my timezone?
Only use SerializerMethodField?

Comment: My guess is the datetime you are trying to serializer is in UTC. The default timezone is used to convert naive datetime objects to timezone aware objects

Comment: Convert at the client... This way each client can see the dates in his own timezone.

Comment: And not just anywhere at the client, only convert at the presentation layer.  Everything API/backend keep UTC!